# Error in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10),

But when i run the command

```
python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images\train_labels.csv --image_dir=images\train --output_path=train.record
```

i am getting the following error, How can i solve the problems

```
C:\Users\ASUS PC\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 20, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import dataset_util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'object_detection'
```

Answer (score 1):

You've probably forgotten to do this, or to change the paths according to your own installation:

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\tensorflow1\models;C:\tensorflow1\models\research;C:\tensorflow1\models\research\slim
```

You should replace `C:\tensorflow1\models` with the path to your tensorflow/models directory on your computer.

Or you have exited your virtual environment and come back to it, so you need to use this command again. (see section 2e of your linked tutorial)